# Python Loop to Create Sheets Using Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to create a loop to add sheets to an excel file based on names in a list. For some reason it is not working. Would appreciate some help.

```
import openpyxl

worksheets = ['Balance Sheet Entries',
              'Production Costs',
              'Model - Realised',
              'Orders',
              'Manufacturing Comparison',
              'Unit Economics']

# File where new sheets should be created
template = openpyxl.load_workbook('New File.xlsx')

#Loop through worksheets and create one new sheet using each name in the list.
for i in range(len(worksheets)):
    template.create_sheet(worksheets[i]) #or template.create_sheet(title=worksheets[i])
```

The outcome of running this is exactly nothing. Nothing happens to the file and the code runs fine "Process finished with exit code 0".

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The pythonic way to loop through a list is `for worksheet in worksheets`.

Comment: @SuperStormer yes, thanks for that. I'm still a beginner on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick scan through the docs suggests you need to call `template.save(filename)` in order to actually save to disk.